# SQL in AR searching if an element is not within a column array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

date = Date.today

```
Subscription.joins(:cart).where("'#{date.beginning_of_week(:sunday).to_s}' != ANY (carts.skipped_weeks)")
```

The column skipped_weeks on Cart is an array of dates like ["2017-04-10", "2017-04-17"]

I am running the above query and still receiving and records that have a date included on the cart.skipped_weeks column array, I only want records that do not include that date in the skipped_weeks array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports [`all`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21126) as well as `any`:

> **9.23.4. ALL (array)**
>
> ```
> expression operator ALL (array expression)
> ```
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given `operator`, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of `ALL` is "true" if all comparisons yield true (including the case where the array has zero elements). The result is "false" if any false result is found.

Saying:

```
where('? != all(carts.skilled_weeks)', date.beginning_of_week(:sunday))
```

would probably be a more readable match for your intended logic.

Comment: is there any  added benefit to using ALL vs ANY?

Comment: Not likely, just a question of readability and preference. The query optimizer probably knows De Morgan's Laws well enough to translate.

Answer (score 1):

```
Subscription.joins(:cart).where("NOT '#{date.beginning_of_week(:sunday).to_s}' = ANY (carts.skipped_weeks)")
```

Here is the correct form